# How to check parameter then define attribute python class

Tags: python, oop, attributes, queue, init

I have a class Queue as below, In this class if I don't transmission capacity it will set isLimit and vice versa I don't know if there is a more efficient way

```
class Queue():
    def __init__(self, capacity=None):
        self._queue = list()
        if(capacity ==None):
            self.isLimit = False
        else:
            self.isLimit=True
            self.capacity = capacity
```

Comment: Efficient *in what sense*? This code is fine, albeit slightly unidiomatic. Generally, you want `if capacity is None: ...` and maybe you should set `self.capacity` in the `if` block as well (maybe to `None`?) but none of that has anything to do with *efficiency*, rather, with design

Comment: The islimit attribute is redundant.  If capacity is None, islimit == False, if capacity is not none islimit is True.  Just check for capacity is None!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of use a variable `isLimit`, you can use only the variable `capacity` and verify if it's `None` or not:

```py
class Queue():
    def __init__(self, capacity=None):
        self._queue = list()
        self._capacity = capacity
    
    def can_add_more(self):
        if self._capacity is None:  # Doesn't have a limit
            return True
        return len(self._queue) < self._capacity
```

Comment: This is a good way to go about it, but overall I don't know if the efficiency of the algorithm is improved, but the efficiency of coding is improved a great deal.